# WMIC Command Not Working in For Loop of Batch File

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, wmi, wmi-query, wmic

I have a batch file that I am trying to run, but I keep getting an error. I think that this question is similar to [I can't get the right syntax to use WMIC in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249147/i-cant-get-the-right-syntax-to-use-wmic-in-batch-file?answertab=votes#tab-top), but dbenham's answer doesn't completely work in my case because I am piping to findstr. Here is a part of the batch file (the part it is hanging on):

for /F %%I in ('wmic nic where 'Manufacturer!="Microsoft" and Macaddress IS NOT NULL' get index ^| findstr /r [0-9]') do (
echo %%I
)

The wmic command works just fine if you run it from cmd or it's own line of a batch file, but I cannot get it to run in the for loop. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic nic where "manufacturer!=\"Microsoft\" and macaddress is not null" get macaddress /format:list 2^>NUL'
) do echo %%I
```

You have to backslash-escape your quoted stuff where your quotes are nested.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That seemed to do the trick. Is using the list format and the delim you set better than piping to findstr? Also, can you tell me what the 2>null does? I have seen this before, but didn't know anything about it.

Comment: Yeah, running a single command is more efficient than piping the output through `findstr`.  The `2>NUL` redirects stderr to a black hole.  The reason I put that there is purely cosmetic.  `wmic` often prints empty lines to stderr for no good reason.  Redirecting stderr to nothingness hides those useless line breaks.  The redirection is not necessary, but it's just force of habit for me to include it when using `wmic`.  Anyway, see [Batch Files - Redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in WMIC that it sometimes waits for user input.

If you replace

```
wmic
```

in your example, with

```
echo. ^| wmic
```

it will allow the command to complete